# How to make HTML "a" tag transition delay?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a smooth transition using html "a" element to move from a div to another div.

```css
p {
  min-height: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"><a href="#second">Click me to go to the div with id second</a></div>
<p>Many texts and paragraphs that separate the 2 divs</p>
<div id="second"><a href="#first">Click me to go to the div
```

By clicking on the first link, you go to the second div and vice versa. However, the moving (transition) back and forth happen instantly and I would like to know how to make it move more smoothly (with 0.2s delay in transition).

I try the CSS property "transition" but yield no result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: what you looking for is called `smooth-scroll behavior` whioch works by using anchors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using JQuery for this:

```js
$("#button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top
  }, 3000); //Change Smoothness Here
});
```

```css
p {
  min-height: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first"><a id="button" href="#second">Click me to go to the div with id second</a></div>
<p>Many texts and paragraphs that separate the 2 divs</p>
<div id="second"><a href="#first">Click me to go to the div</a></div>
```

This basically prevents the basic scrolling and animates a scroll that goes for 3 seconds untill it gets to the div you want it to get to.

Comment: why not use the default css line: `scroll-behavior: smooth;` which can do this without a script?

Comment: @tacoshy It doesn’t have support in IE- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: @tacoshy, Also, testing on Safari 14, it wasn’t working for me.